# Gzip no such file or directory error, still zips files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm just learning shell scripting specifically in bash, I want to be able to use gzip to take files from a target directory and send them to a different directory. I enter directories in the command line. ext is for the extensions I want to zip and file will be the new zipped file. **My script zips the files correctly**, to and from the desired directories, **but I get a no such file or directory error**. How do I avoid this?

Current code

```
cd $1

for ext in $*; do
    for file in `ls *.$ext`; do
        gzip -c $file > $2/$file.gz
    done 
done
```

and my I/O

```
blackton@ltsp-amd64-charlie:~/Desktop/60256$ bash myCompress /home/blackton/Desktop/ /home/blackton/ txt
ls: cannot access *./home/blackton/Desktop/: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access *./home/blackton/: No such file or directory
gzip: alg: No such file or directory
gzip: proj.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `find * -name "*.$ext" -type f` instead of `ls *.$ext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate things causing problems here.
In your outer loop

```
for ext in $*; do
done
```

you are looping over all the command line parameters, using each as the extension to search for - including the directory names.

Since the extension is the third parameter, you only want to run the inner loop once on `$3`:

```
for file in `ls *.$3`; do
    gzip -c $file > $2/$file.gz
done
```

The next problem is spaces.

You do not want to run `ls` here - the wildcard expansion will provide the filenames directly, e.g. `for file in *.$3`, and it will fill `$file` with a whole filename at a time. The output from `ls` is split on each space, so you end up with two filenames `alg` and `proj.txt`, instead of one `alg proj.txt`.

That is not enough by itself, though. You also need to quote `$file` whenever you use it, so the command expands to `gzip -c "alg proj.txt"` instead of `gzip -c alg proj.txt`, which tells gzip to compress two files. In general, all variable expansions that you expect to be a filename should be quoted:

```
cd "$1"

for file in *."$3"; do
    gzip -c "$file" > "$2/$file.gz"
done
```

One further problem is that if there are no files matching the extension, the wildcard will not expand and the command executed will be

```
gzip -c "*.txt" > "dir/*.txt.gz"
```

This will create a file that is literally called "*.txt.gz" in the target directory. A simple way to avoid this would be to check that the original file exists first - this will also avoid accidentally trying to gzip an oddly named directory.

```
cd "$1"

for file in *."$3"; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        gzip -c "$file" > "$2/$file.gz"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I originally had two for loops in order to get multiple extensions but I now realize I was looking at the entire command line. If I wanted to enter multiple file extensions, is there a way to look at only certain parameters from the command line? Or perhaps even if I kept the the outer loop but implemented the if statement to avoid looking to zip other files?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to use `shift`. It throws away $1 and moves all the other parameters down by one. You could call it twice to clear away the input and output directories and then use $* as you did originally, or perhaps do some sort of "while $3 is not empty, process that extension, shift" loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
Src=$1
Des=$2
ext="txt"
for file in $Src/*; do
    if [ "${file##*.}" = "${ext}" ]; then
       base=$(basename $file)
       mkdir -p $2  #-p ensures creation if directory does not exist
       gzip -c $file > $Des/$base.gz
    fi
done
```